# Summation and product proof by induction

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in [0,1]$ be real numbers.
Show that
$$1-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)$$

I am aware that the product on the right-hand side is equal to 0$$, so we just have to show that the left-hand side is smaller than $0$. I tried to arrange the inequality with some properties of summations or products, but I'm really confused as to how to set up my inductive hypothesis and furthermore step.

Comment: The product is only $0$ if $a_j=1$ for some $j$. Some choices of the $a_j$ also obtain $1-\sum_ia_i>0$, i.e. $\sum_ia_i<1$.

Comment: @Macavity *Who* can't see it? It's closed, not deleted.

Comment: @Macavity What is viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege is the *reason* why the post got closed, not the post itself.

Comment: @Macavity If you still have doubts, you can proceed as follows: open that page (the one with the closed question) with a web browser that you normally don't use (and that doesn't know your identity as a StackExchange user). In other words, see that page as an anonymous user. You will be able to read it. What you will not see is the list of the names of those who voted to close it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. Thanks for that clarification, tried that out, it works as you say.

Answer (score 1):

In fact even a non-negative integer $n$ works: the base case $n=0$ is trivial, as both expressions are then $1$. (If you only care about $n\ge1$, note the case $n=1$ is an easy base too because both sides are then $1-a_1$.) For the inductive step from $n=k$ to $n=k+1$,$$1-\sum_{i\le k+1}a_i\le1-\sum_{i\le k+1}a_i+a_{k+1}\sum_{i\le k}a_i=\left(1-\sum_{i\le k}a_i\right)(1-a_{k+1})\le\prod_{j\le k+1}(1-a_j),$$where only the last step uses the inductive hypothesis.